# Prove the identity $x^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0}S_{n,k}(x)_k$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

> Prove the following identity: $$x^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0}S_{n,k}(x)_k \space \space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (n \geq 0)$$.

We are talking clearly about Stirling numbers of the second kind here. I don't know what exactly $(x)_k$ means, but in my script I have something defined like this:

$$x_0 := 1$$

$$(x)_n := x(x-1)(x-2)\ldots(x-n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n+k}s_{n,k}x^k$$

Any ideas about what it exactly talks about and how can I prove this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x)_k$ can be expressed as $\frac{x!}{(k-1)!} = \binom{x}{k}k!$

To distribute $n$ distinct objects into $x$ distinct boxes with empty boxes allowed, we have $$x^n \space \text{ways}$$

Or we could choose $k$ boxes to distribute the $n$ objects into with no empty boxes allowed, from $k=0$ to $k=n$

To choose the $k$ boxes we have $\binom{x}{k}$ ways.

To distribute $n$ objects into the $k$ boxes with no empty boxes allowed, we have:
$$k!S_{n,k} \space \text{ways}$$

Therefore, the number of ways to $n$ distinct objects into $x$ distinct boxes with empty boxes allowed, we have:

$$x^n = \sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{x}{k}k!S_{n,k} $$

Comment: What if $x\not\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The combinatorial approach only works for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. So I guess it only proves the identity for $x,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: On the other hand, both sides of the original identity are polynomials in $x$. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: I didn't totally understood why we need the $k!$ in $k!S_{n,k}$. Isn't the definition of Stirling numbers of the second kind enough, which says that number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets.

Comment: @Nicholas I second portal here. I didn't get it too.

Comment: For sirling numbers, it involves distribution into identical boxes, the $k!$ is required since we are dealing with distinct boxes in this case.

Comment: @Nicholas Okay, and one more question, as you have said Stirling numbers count the distribution with no empty boxes allowed, so we go over all the possible Stirling numbers, which counts distributions with no empty boxes, and you conclude that it is the same as counting distributions with empty boxes allowed.

Comment: The initial distribution allowed empty boxes. What we were attempting to do was to split this into the cases where the objects were only distributed into a limited number of $k$ boxes, $k =0,1,2,3 \dots n$. When we are trying to distribute into only $2$ boxes for example, we must then ensure that none of the $2$ boxes are empty otherwise there will be an overlap with the case where we distribute into $1$ box.

Comment: So, $\sum^{n}_{k=0}\binom{x}{k}$  part gives us the number of partitioning $n$ elements into $k$ boxes, which clearly includes the empty boxes too, and $S_{n,k}$ is enough to show that we can distribute $n$ objects into $k$ partitions. But, you have $k!$, which is the combination of all boxes. Clearly, I don't understand the meaning of distinct and identical boxes. Perhaps, an example?

Comment: @portal Let's say we have objects $a,b,c$. If we were to distribute them into two identical boxes, then $(a)(b,c)$ would be the same as $(b,c)(a)$. Now, if we were distribute them into two distinct boxes, say, box $A$ and $B$, $A:(a)$ $B:(b,c)$ would not be the same as $A:(b,c)$ $B:(a)$

Answer (score 2):

That is trivial to prove by assuming that $x$ is a non-negative integer.
 Assume that $|A|=n$ and $|B|=x$.

The LHS counts the number of functions $f:A\to B$. The RHS counts the number of functions from $A$ to $B$, according to the size of $f(A)$, since the Stirling number $S_{n,k}$ accounts for the number of ways for partitioning $A$ in $k$ pieces.

On the other hand, if two polynomials agree on $\mathbb{N}$, they agree on $\mathbb{R}$, too, and that proves the identity in the general case.

Comment: Can you please open this up a bit, I didn't exactly understood what's going on here. Plus, what exactly is $(x)_k$? And you are talking if $x$ is a positive number, what happens if it is negative?

Comment: A non-negative integer is a natural number. $(x)_k$ is a Pochhammer symbol, you know its definition.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Okay, I understood the concept of Pochhammer symbol. But, I still have a hard time grasping the second paragraph of the solution, regarding the LHS and RHS of the identity. Can you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: @portal: simply, $x^n$ is a polynomial, and $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\brace k}(x)_k$ is a polynomial, too. The first part of the proof gives that these polynomials agree on $\mathbb{N}$, hence they agree everywhere.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, what you try to do makes sense, if they agree on NN they will agree everywhere. But, I don't see how LHS counts the number of functions $f:A→B$, I mean what kind of function is surjective or? I know that the Stirling number accounts for the number of ways to partition nn objects into $k$ pieces, but what does it mean to count the number of functions from $A$ to $B$ according to the size of $f(A)$?

Answer (score 0):

This also has a straightforward algebraic proof for $x=q$ with $q$ an integer which then extends to $q$ a complex number.

Recall the combinatorial  species  of  set
partitions which is given by

$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z})),$$

producing the generating function
$$\exp(u(\exp(z)-1))$$
and in particular
$${n\brace k}
= n! [z^n] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Now we have
$$q^n = 
\frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp(qz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (\exp(z)-1)^p\; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} \times p! \times \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^p}{p!}\; dz.$$

Extracting the coefficient we obtain
$$\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} \times p! \times {n\brace p}.$$

But $${q\choose p} \times p! = q^{\underline{p}}$$
and we have the claim.

Answer (score 0):

See http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ICS/malalla/Teaching/ICS253/TextBook/Apps_Ch6.pdf

page 102 on the pdf gives a nice explanation

The falling-factorial $x_k$ represents the number one-to-one functions from a $x$-set to a $k$-set

$S_{n,k}$ represents the number of $k$ sized partitions of n

So, we have $x_k$ $k$ sized partitions, and $S_{n,k}$ ways to organize these $k$ sized partitions

Answer (score 0):

This identity can be proven by induction on $n$. The base case is trivial $x^0 = 1 = S_{0,0}(x)_0$. For the induction case we have 
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}S_{n+1,k}(x)_k &= \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}(S_{n,k-1}+k S_{n,k})(x)_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}S_{n,k-1}(x)_k + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}k S_{n,k}(x)_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}S_{n,k}(x)_{k+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}k S_{n,k}(x)_k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(x-k)S_{n,k}(x)_{k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n}k S_{n,k}(x)_k\\
&=x \sum_{k=0}^{n}S_{n,k}(x)_{k}.
\end{align}
Then by the induction hypothesis we obtain $\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}S_{n+1,k}(x)_k = x^{n+1}$.